# Masters Theorem constant K and Polynomial Difference

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, logarithms

In my lecture notes I noticed for case 2 of masters theorem there is constant "k".
Where does that constant come from?

[image]

Also if f(n) and (n^log b a) is not polynomial different from each other, why not conclude it as case 2?

example: $$ T(n) = 2T (n/2) + n/ log n $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $f(n) = \Theta(n^{log_b^a}log^kn) $ for $k \ge 0$.

$k = 0$ for the first line of formula in your post.

The $k$ come from the bounding function $n^{log_b^a}log^kn$ for large N. To find k, you need to prove, there exists constant $C_1 > 0$ and $C_2 > 0$, such that
$$ C_1 n log^k n = C_1 n^{log_b^a}log^kn < f(n) < C_2 n^{log_b^a}log^kn = C_2nlog^kn$$

Now look at $f(n) = n/logn(n)$, $c = log_2(2) = 1$, we can not find $k \ge 0$ sunc that the above inequality is true. So case 2 cannot be applied.